# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence how do i fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Given problem:**

> Given 4 integers, A, B, C, D, they can be arranged as

```
 A B
 C D
```

> then the table value of this table is `(A/C-B/D)`
>   If we rotate 90 degrees clockwise, then we have

```
 C A
 D B
```

> Then the table value is `C/D -A/B`
>
> Give 4 integers, implement a function table(A, B, C, D) which returns
>   the minimum number of clockwise rotations required for the maximum of
>   the table value.

**Implementation**

Implement a function `table(A, B, C, D)`,
where A, B, C and D are integers and  0

Sample

```
table(1, 2 , 3 ,4) = 3
```

**Here is my code**

```
def table(a, b, c, d):

    x = [[a, b, c, d], [c, a, d, b], [d, c, b, a], [b, d, a, c]]
    ans = []

    for count in range(4):
        if (x[count][2] == 0 or x[count][3] == 0) and x[count][0] != 0 and x[count][1] != 0:
            y = -(x[count][0] / x[count][1])
        elif x[count][2] != 0 and x[count][3] != 0 and (x[count][0] == 0 or x[count][1] == 0):
            y = x[count][2] / x[count][3]
        elif x[count][2] == 0 and x[count][3] == 0 and x[count][0] == 0 and x[count][1] == 0:
            y = 0
        else:
            y = x[count][2] / x[count][3] - x[count][0] / x[count][1]

        ans.append(y)
    print(ans)
    temp = ans
    for count in range(4):
        z = temp[0]
        temp.remove(temp[0])
        if z not in temp:
            return ans.index(max(ans)) + 1
    return 0


import time
x = time.time()
print(table(0, 0, 0, 0))
print(time.time() - x)
```

Upon running, it throws these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[0, 0, 0, 0]
  File "C:/Users/lisha/PycharmProjects/untitled/lab 5 qn 2.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(table(0, 0, 0, 0))
  File "C:/Users/lisha/PycharmProjects/untitled/lab 5 qn 2.py", line 22, in table
    return ans.index(max(ans)) + 1
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone please point the error out?

Comment: Given that you print `ans` right above, I'm really not sure what's tried you up here.

Comment: At each of the four iterations, you remove the first element of `temp` and then call `max` on what's left. Since initially `temp` has 4 values, it naturally becomes empty before the last call to `max`. Hint: You want `temp = ans.copy()`.

Comment: You can replace your second loop with `return ans.index(max(ans)) + 1`. Btw, the expected output for the example you gave is inconsistent with the text - initial configuration requires zero rotations, that's why the third entry in your ans requires actually only 2 rotations (remove `+1` in that `return`).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through your code logic but I am pretty sure that where things go wrong is

```
temp = ans
```

you are setting temp to reference the same object as ans and so they are the same. I mean they are literally the same. then when you remove item from temp you also remove item from ans as side effect. To solve it I suggest using

```
temp = ans[:]
```

which creates a copy of `ans` and assigns it to temp then when you remove from `temp` the ans wouldn't change.

you can check whether to variables reference to same object by using `is` key word so

```
temp = ans
print(temp is ans) # True
```

but

```
temp = ans[:]
print(temp is ans) # False
```

another thing to notice is that this happens because lists are mutable. but int, str, tupples are not so there is a difference.